# Error: [ng:areq] Argument Controller is Not a Function

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to load a blank google maps app in my rails app (I will be adding markers later via facotries, etc). This format worked in my last project, but unfortunately I can't get it to load this time around.

I used Bower via `bower install angular`, but it seems I'm setting an error `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MapController' is not a function, got undefined` from the browser with a red line where the map should be. It made sure all the namespaces matched but its still coming up short.

What is also strange is this `ng:areq` error is coming from a public assets file, not the files below (file `application-1f030c1aa52b19b22da2952dccdcd4ba.js:6`)

**ERRORS**

Console errors:
`var injector = angular.injector(['Sessions_Map', 'ng']);` returns `undefined`

`MapController` returns `MapController is not defined`

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MapController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=MapController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at Mt (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at _t (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at x (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at vt (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at g (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at g (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42(anonymous function) @ application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
```

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require map_app.js
```

**map_app.js**

```
var Sessions_Map = angular.module('Sessions_Map' , []);

Sessions_Map.controller('MapController', function($scope){
  });

    Sessions_Map.directive("myMaps", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,


        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.029732, -118.449528),
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), mapOptions);
           }
        };
    });
```

**Map.html.erb**

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="Sessions_Map">
<head>

<%= javascript_include_tag "map_app.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>


<title>
    Google Maps
</title>
<style>

    #map-canvas{
        height:650px;
        width:1050px;
        border:2px solid red;
    }

 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcRGSjkX4Meav-RxEzY4SXQnVwKnedZvE">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body ng-controller="MapController">
<my-maps id="map-canvas"></my-maps>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What you mean by `locations` in your controller parameter?

Comment: With require, you mean you are actually using RequireJS or something similar? Because your code seems to [work](https://jsfiddle.net/7n79osy9/)

Comment: @RameshRajendran, those are variables I'm going to fill in later with backend calls to my server.

Comment: @Michael I took this code from a project I worked on at another company. I assumed I had requireJS. Should I add that gem for rails ?

Comment: @Michael I added the errors abobe. There is an issue loading angular animate, as well as map_app.js

Comment: Move all the script from body to head section and keep body tag clean and below head. Javascript is interpreted.

Comment: @jsjunkie moving now, but answer below also notes that those script tags may also be redunant

Comment: Chat here for those interested  @jsjunkie  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75896/angular-maps

Comment: problem seems to be with minification... use `ng-strict-di` and check if that solved the problem

Comment: @entre how/where would that work ?

Comment: just google about `ng-strict-di`, read about it more

Answer (score 1):

> `application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js`

What exactly is your build process / [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)?

### config/application.rb

Did you configure your asset paths properly?

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("...stuff...")
```

### app/map_app.js

note you are creating a new module (passing an empty `requires` array)

```
var Sessions_Map = angular.module('Sessions_Map' , []);  // create
```

which you are later creating a second time rather than retrieving it.

```
var Sessions_Map = angular.module('Sessions_Map');  // retrieve
```

### Map.html.erb

I think those 2 blocks should not be there...

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/app/assets/javascripts/angular-animate.min.js.map">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src = "/app/assets/javascripts/app/map_app.js">
</script>
```

since you already have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

which itself has the following requires:

```
//= require angular-animate
//= require app/map_app
```

### minification

From this trace, where functions are named `Mt`, `_t`, `v` and `g` I can see there is minification going on.

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MapController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=MapController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at Mt (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at _t (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
at x (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at vt (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at g (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at g (application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42)
at application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42(anonymous function) @ application-dc67be4c50a7a0828f3e243f50780c24.js:42
```

please make sure to use the correct syntax for the dependency injection to work properly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 ->  "A Note on Minification"

**EDIT**: You can tweak the `uglifier` step in your rails config to look at the result `application-[checksum].js`, and actually see that your controller is in there.

### EDIT:

> `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

It is possible that somewhere in your code you are loading angular twice, and possibly messing up the previous module declaration.

Comment: First, how I am creating the modulw twice ? Let me review this on my app. I tried and failed with a few different methods and ended up with bower. I am using the following   `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')`

Comment: I added a chat that might be easier (I'll still ward you bounty regardless!) : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75896/angular-maps

Comment: This helped clean up code but still left with that one sole error

Comment: Would `config.assets.js_compressor = Sprockets::LazyCompressor.new { Uglifier.new(mangle: false) }` help for the minifier ?

Comment: I was able to fix the `Loading Angluar more than once` warning by changing in `map.html.erb` to  `<%= javascript_include_tag "map_app.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Comment: While this did not completly answer the question, it was the most helpful and thus awarded the bounty